# Finding string element in array with integers using lodash includes not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lodash

Here's my code, i'm using vuejs:

```
pins: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0], //my data

isThisPin(pin){
    return _.includes(this.pins, pin);
}

console.log(this.isThisPin('X')); //it returns true
```

Basically i'm trying to guess if the selected pin is not included in the pins, I expect to return it as false, but it just keep returning as true.

Am I using a wrong function?

Comment: you are not using `pin` but `X`

Comment: Try this var pins = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];
console.log(pins.includes(1));

Comment: @AZ_ sorry for typo, I'll edit it. It should be pin, and passing 'X' as value.

Comment: I don't see any error. It is returning `false` for `console.log(this.isThisPin('X'))`. see https://repl.it/repls/SuperImpressiveSite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your **pins** array is as simple as that, you don't need anything just vanilla JavaScript.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    pins: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    pin: '',
    result: ''
  },
  methods: {
    isThisPin() {
      if (this.pin) {
        this.result = this.pins.includes(Number(this.pin))
      } else {
        this.result = ''
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <label>IS THIS PIN: <input type="number" v-model="pin" @input="isThisPin"></label>
  <br /> RESULT: {{result}}
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, it work now. I still used the _.includes function, but I added the `Number(pin)` and it worked.

Comment: Then it was a type problem. I’m happy that I could help! :)

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with plain javascript:

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"]
var a = fruits.indexOf("Apple")
```

Returns index of the item or -1 if not found

or

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var n = fruits.includes("Mango");
```

Returns true or false

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use lodash you use _.contains also the snippet works with lodash

```
_.contains([1, 2, 3], 'X') // false
```

```js
var pins = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];
//alert(_.includes(pins, 'X'));

function checkPin(pin){
  return _.includes(pins,pin )
}

alert(checkPin('X'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: it catches TypeError: `_.contains is not a function` i'm using lodash 4.17.13

Comment: _contains is not in the version you use! it is in previous versions the above snippet works with _.includes ! See https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#countBy

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) as below

```js
var pins = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];
console.log( pins.findIndex(e => e == 'x') != -1 );
console.log( pins.findIndex(e => e == 9) != -1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, your snippet does work and `_.includes` does work - run snippet to check. Therefore the problem must be somewhere else.

```js
const pins = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];

function isThisPin(pin) {
  return _.includes(this.pins, pin);
}

console.log(this.isThisPin('X'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```